Java Bluecove Bluetooth connection
I'm trying to make a bluetooth connection between my JavaFX application and a Bluetooth device. To achieve that I followed the example bluetooth-java-client.
Here the info about the bluetooth device:

The problem is that the connection is established but drops immediately after.
The scan works well and is practically identical to the example.
I tried to open the connection in two different ways:

StreamConnection scConnection = (StreamConnection) Connector.open("btspp://" + strAddress + ":1");
L2CAPConnection scConnection = (L2CAPConnection) Connector.open("btl2cap://" + strAddress + ":1");

Once the connection is obtained, I open the streams, start the reading thread and send the first packet:


     RemoteDevice rdRemoteDevice = RemoteDevice.getRemoteDevice(scConnection);
     this.strDeviceName = rdRemoteDevice.getFriendlyName(false);
     this.isInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(scConnection.openInputStream());
     this.osOutputStream = scConnection.openOutputStream();



     // I've implemented a sort of queue, one thread fill it and the other empties it
     Thread tReceiverThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             receiveBluetoothData();
         }
     });
     tReceiverThread.start();
     Thread tReaderThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             readMessagePoolData();
         }
     });
     tReaderThread.start();



     try {
         sWriterSemaphore.acquire();

         bytLastSentPacket = createPacketToSend(eDataType, strPayload);
         Logger.getAnonymousLogger().log(Level.INFO, TAGS.BLUETOOTH + "Created packet " + ((char) eDataType.value) + " with payload '" + strPayload + "'");

         osOutputStream.write(bytLastSentPacket);
         osOutputStream.flush();

         /*
           Sometimes I see the following line in the logs but most of the time
           the connection drops before.
         */
         Logger.getAnonymousLogger().log(Level.INFO, TAGS.BLUETOOTH + "The packet " + Arrays.toString(bytLastSentPacket) + " has been sent to " + strDeviceName);
     } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
         Logger.getAnonymousLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, TAGS.BLUETOOTH + "Error writing to " + strDeviceName + " output stream", e);
     }



Here's the logs:
2024-10-08 09:18:53.337 [INFO   ] [BLUETOOTH       ] Starting device discovery... 
2024-10-08 09:19:04.037 [INFO   ] [BLUETOOTH       ] New device discovered: [3481F4326C73 - HK_Star_175-005] 
2024-10-08 09:19:04.346 [INFO   ] [BLUETOOTH       ] New device discovered: [3481F4326CB0 - HK_Star_2013001] 
2024-10-08 09:19:04.448 [INFO   ] [BLUETOOTH       ] Device discovery completed 
2024-10-08 09:19:53.421 [INFO   ] [BLUETOOTH       ] Ready to read messages from HK_Star_2013001 
2024-10-08 09:19:53.466 [INFO   ] [BLUETOOTH       ] Created packet Y with payload '' 
2024-10-08 09:19:53.480 [SEVERE ] [BLUETOOTH       ] Error writing to HK_Star_2013001 output stream 
java.io.IOException: Failed to write. [107] Transport endpoint is not connected
    at bluecove@2.1.1/com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothStackBlueZ.connectionRfWrite(Native Method)
    at bluecove@2.1.1/com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothRFCommOutputStream.write(BluetoothRFCommOutputStream.java:84)
    at java.base/java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:122)
    at com.mycompany.myproject/com.mycompany.myproject.utils.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.sendBluetoothData(BluetoothDevice.java:144)
    at com.mycompany.myproject/com.mycompany.myproject.utils.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.<init>(BluetoothDevice.java:94)
    at com.mycompany.myproject/com.mycompany.myproject.utils.bluetooth.BluetoothHelper.openConnection(BluetoothHelper.java:66)
    at com.mycompany.myproject/com.mycompany.myproject.controllers.users.Login$2.handle(Login.java:107)
    at com.mycompany.myproject/com.mycompany.myproject.controllers.users.Login$2.handle(Login.java:98)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base@19/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8923)
    at javafx.controls@19/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
    at javafx.controls@19/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:207)
    at javafx.controls@19/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base@19/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3894)
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1887)
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2620)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:551)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:316)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

